# Options for Member Restriction of data (eg entries)

Tags: members

I have a few member groups and I've setup matching Channels to manage restrictions for those different groups.

I actually know the answer to this question for a base install of EE. The only restriction option available on a Member Group basis is Channel.

Are there any techniques for improving on this? Or maybe 3rd party Add-ons I'm not aware of.

Eg.
10 member groups all with restricted access just to entries they can edit/publish (ie named Channels). I now need to setup a News channel. All members can publish a news story that also needs to be 'tagged' with their business area (one of 10). An obvious option for this would be 1 Channel called News with 10 Categories.

The issues is I don't want any member from member group 5 being able to edit or publish to member group 6. There isn't an option to restrict member groups by category.

The only option I can see at the moment is duplicating the News Channel 10 times! Applying Channel Assignment and including 10 channel names in my entries tag. Not very elegant.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are your members using the control panel or Safecracker to publish/edit?

Comment: CP. I'm baffled by everyone recreating the CP experience.

Answer (score 1):

You may not be able to restrict member groups to categories in the control panel, but you could certainly do it in your templates if they're adding/editing content on the front end via Safecracker.

And just did a quick search on Devotee, and even though the intro for [Entry Access](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/entry-access) says it's for use on the front end, if you read further down, it says:

> The restrictions also apply to editing entry from CP.
>
> Default permissions (for a new entry) can be set in extension settings.

Comment: Thanks for the Entry Access link but it isn't a solution. The entries need to be resticted by a member group automatically. I can see how this would work well for 'pages' of a site or existing entries. I'm really not a fan of Safecracker, this is a large complex site build, on reason I'm using EE because of it's CP!

Comment: … THE reason I'm using EE